# How to increase a magic number in a file buffer on each save

Tags: hooks, saving, auto-insert

I want to change a magic number (or a time stamp) **in** a file buffer on each save. The position of the magic number in the buffer can be given through a regex with a keyword or similar.

Is there any package for this? I tried `auto-insert` which comes with Emacs 26, but this seems to only update on file buffer *creation*, not on each save.

I preferably would like to enable this on a per-file basis through file local variables.

I tried a custom hack via `before-save-hook`, but struggled to add a function to this hook through afile variable declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>C-h f time-stamp</kbd>:

```
time-stamp is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
`time-stamp.el'.

(time-stamp)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.31.

Update the time stamp string(s) in the buffer.
A template in a file can be automatically updated with a new time stamp
every time you save the file.  Add this line to your init file:
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
or customize `before-save-hook' through Custom.
```

If you want to do this in the local variables section, you need to use
the 'eval' functionality. e.g. assuming a .c file:

```
/* Local Variables: */
/* eval: (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp 0 t) */
/* End: */
```

will cause the *local* value of `before-save-hook` to containg
`time-stamp`.

Comment: This works, thanks. However I cannot figure out how to set add `time-stamp` to `before-save-hook` *in the file-local variables* at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with file-local-variables. If you put the 'add-hook' in your init file, 'time-stamp' will run every time you save a buffer. For files which don't have a time-stamp template in the first 8 lines, nothing will be done, for files which do the time-stamp will be updated

Comment: Sure, but that's exactly what I want to avoid: That *all* files with the time-stamp template are updated on save.  Therfore I thought a buffer local `before-save-hook` set in the file-local variables would do the trick - but I cannot figure out how to add to hooks in the file-local variables...

Comment: Cool, `eval` does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easily done via a file-local variable `save-count`.
The only drawback is that you cannot define the format of the magick number freely but you are bound to the format of file-local variables.

```el
(defvar save-count nil
  "To be used as file-local variable.
Number of times the buffer file has been saved.")

(put 'save-count 'safe-local-variable #'numberp)

(defun start-save-count (&optional remove)
  "Start counting saves for the current buffer file."
  (interactive "P")
  (if remove
      (delete-file-local-variable 'save-count)
    (add-file-local-variable 'save-count 0))
  (normal-mode))

(defun update-save-count ()
  "Increment file local variable `save-count' if its value is a number."
  (when (numberp save-count)
    (cl-incf save-count)
    (save-excursion
      (add-file-local-variable 'save-count save-count))))


(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'update-save-count)
```

If you do not set the value of `save-count` to a number you do not get the counter.

That offers you several possibilities:

- Preferred way: You can call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `start-save-count`. That command adds `save-count` to the list of file local variables in the current buffer. It also runs `normal-mode` for that variable to become effective.
- You can just add a file local variable `save-count` with numeric value to your file. This will automatically be incremented on saves.
- You can globally set `save-count` to a numeric value. In that case all buffers will get such a value on first save.
- You can set the buffer-local value of `save-count` with `(setq-local save-count 0)`. Then you get the save count just for that buffer file.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, but I want to change a magic number given as characters in the buffer itself - and this number should be updated on every save. I don't need a *variable* with a number...

Comment: @halloleo Have you really tried it?  The value is stored as value of the file local variable in the file! That **is** a character sequence in the file!

Comment: @halloleo I have added a command `start-save-count` to ease the application. Just open any text file where you want to start counting the saves and call `M-x start-save-count`. Everything other will work automatically.

Comment: @halloleo Note, the motivation for my answer was 1st: the word *increase* in the title of the question and 2nd: the phrase *magic number* in the text before you added "*(or a time-stamp)*".

Comment: Sorry, Tobias, I hadn't tried it. Now I have and indeed it increments the value text of the variable _in_ the buffer. Pretty nifty!